# $H^1(G,A)\rightarrow H^1(H,A)$ is onto

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, group-cohomology

Note that $H^1(G,A)\rightarrow H^1(H,A)^{G/H}$ where $A$ is $G$-module and $H$ is a subgroup in $G$

> But I suspect that ${\rm Res}\ : \ H^1(G,A)\rightarrow H^1(H,A)$ may be onto

since $ f\in C^n (G,A)\mapsto f|_{H\times \cdots \times H} \in C^n(H,A)$ is onto.

Do I miss some ?

Comment: You already pointed out that $\operatorname{Res}$ sends $H^1(G)$ into the invariants $H^1(H)^{G/H}$, not the whole cohomology group. Even though the cochain map is onto, passing from cochain to cohomology changes a lot.

Comment: What does $H^1(H,A)^{G/H}$ mean if $H$ is not normal ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the map isn't onto  in general. It's easy to construct counterexamples.

In fact, every non-abelian p-group (more general: nilpotent group) yields a counterexample. For, let $G$ be a non-abelian p-group. Since each non-trivial normal subgroup intersects the center non-trivially, we find a central subgroup $1 \neq C \subseteq [G,G] \subsetneqq G$.

$\text{Res}: H^1(G,\mathbb{F}_p) \to H^1(C,\mathbb{F}_p)=H^1(C,\mathbb{F}_p)^{G/C}$ is the restriction $Hom(G,\mathbb{F}_p) \to Hom(C,\mathbb{F}_p)$ which is **zero** because $f \in Hom(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$ vanishes on $[G,G]$.